# How do I select items in range of a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

My database is in MySQL.

Assume I have the following table:

```
id         number
1          45
2          25
3          66
4          43
......
......
......
30         54
31         21
```

etc ... etc.

I want to have a query like so:

select * from myTable where number = 25

but I want to also include 2 more items, one above it and one below it (based on ID).

the result set of my query would turn up with the following result set: 1, 2, 3.

If I selected the number 66, then the result set would include 2, 3, 4. Etc, etc.

The idea would be to range the query by saying, hey, I want anything that has an ID equal to 1 minus this queries' id, and also one plus this queries' id.

I hope this makes sense.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

P.S.
The point of this is to capture events in a log so that I can see what happened before and after a certain event happened

Comment: is `number` unique? What should happen if the `25` appears more than once in the table?

Comment: number is not unique. If 25 appears twice, the the total number of results would be six.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
    myTable AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id
      FROM myTable
      WHERE number = 25
    ) AS my
  ON t.id BETWEEN my.id - 1 AND my.id + 1 ;
```

Notice that this will **not** show 3 rows if your ids have gaps.

Also, if the `number` you choose (25 in the example) appears more than once (but k times), the result will be 3*k rows.

---

If there are gaps, as expected, in the `id` column, you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ( SELECT t.*
    FROM 
        myTable AS t
      JOIN
        ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id
          FROM myTable
          WHERE number = 25
        ) AS my
      ON t.id <= my.id 
    ORDER BY t.id DESC 
      LIMIT 2
  ) AS a

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT t.*
    FROM 
        myTable AS t
      JOIN
        ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id
          FROM myTable
          WHERE number = 25
        ) AS my
      ON t.id > my.id 
    ORDER BY t.id ASC 
      LIMIT 1
  ) AS b ;
```

---

If there are gaps in the `id` column and the `number` is not unique so the parameter (`25`) can appear more than once (but say `k` times), you can have a query that returns `3*k` rows (almost all the times):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
    myTable AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id
      FROM myTable
      WHERE number = 25
    ) AS ti
  ON t.id =
     ( SELECT tt.id
       FROM myTable AS tt
       WHERE tt.id < ti.id
       ORDER BY tt.id DESC
         LIMIT 1
     ) 
  OR t.id = ti.id
  OR t.id =
     ( SELECT tt.id
       FROM myTable AS tt
       WHERE tt.id > ti.id
       ORDER BY tt.id ASC
         LIMIT 1
     ) ;
```

Comment: answerers of your level might provide proof answer, that doesn't rely on consecutive ids ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Is that ok? It seems we posted almost identical answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will work (I remember there are some limitations on `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in `UNION`ed queries, but don't have mysql instance to check it), but what if you try:

```
(SELECT t2.id
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t2.id > t1.id
WHERE t1.number = 25
ORDER BY t2.id
LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT t2.id
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON t2.id < t1.id
WHERE t1.number = 25
ORDER BY t2.id DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id, id-1, id+1 FROM table WHERE number=25)
```

Comment: No one guaranteed id to be strictly consecutive

Comment: oops, I just saw another question with auto_increment and confused it with this one :/